# Is it possible to send a fileList in StanfordNLP API?

Tags: stanford-nlp

As per my knowledge, StanfordNLP API needs to be called with text data, but as per there documents its advised to use fileList to speed up the processing and to avoid loading of models, so is there a way to send fileList in StanfordNLP API for NER or coref or anyother sub module ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
java -Xmx14g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -fileList file_list.txt -outputFormat text
```

You can add any properties you want to the pipeline.

More details here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html
https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

Comment: I wanted to use it for API calls, like the second link you mentioned, there we need to pass text, instead of that I would like to pass a list of text, is that possible using API ?